# **UPDATED** Converting to NSDate using dateFromString gives incorrect results

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have these lines of code, which creates a starting date, based on the first Monday of the week starting 1 second after Midnight:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd '00:00:01' a"];  //  one second after midnight
NSString *startDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:firstDayOfTheWeek];  

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *nsdStart = [formatter dateFromString:startDateString];
```

**startDateString** is 2014-03-31 00:00:01 AM (which is correct)

**nsdStart** is 2014-04-01 00:00:00 PDT (which is wrong!)

Now, I have to do the same for the ending date, with this code:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd '23:59:59' a"];  //  one second before midnight
NSString *endDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:lastDayOfTheWeek];  //  create end date string

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *nsdEnd = [formatter dateFromString:endDateString];  //  convert to NSDate
```

The results are now:
**endDateString**: 2014-04-06 23:59:59 PM (which is correct)

**nsdEnd**:  *nil*

Why is **nsdStart** and **nsdEnd** not the same as original string dates used to create the **nsd** dates?

Comment: What is the value of `firstDayOfWeek` when dumped?

Comment: And what is the value of nsdStart when dumped?

Comment: firstDayOfTheWeek:  2014-03-31 07:00:01 +0000  (I'm in the Pacific time zone).  nsdStart: 2014-04-01 07:00:00 +0000 (same Pacific time zone).

Comment: Why are you setting `@"yyyy-MM-dd '00:00:01' a"` for the first format?  Don't you mean `@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"`?

Comment: @Nicholas Hart: no, I found that piece of code on SO... it takes the date and appends the constant time to it... it works like it's supposed to... also, I just updated the question, so please have a look at the revised code.  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is wrong format for date.

You should use `'HH'` for 24 hour time format instead of `hh`, looks like date formatter confused with `23` hours where max is `12` for that format.

details here :
[Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Using your suggestion of HH, **nsdEnd** is now:  2014-04-06 12:59:59 PDT, which is closer (date is now correct, but time is still incorrect).  **nsdStart** didn't change at all.  (I knew about the patterns already... thanks anyway.)

Comment: Not only that, but in the first case the poor formatter must be confused as heck trying to read an AM/PM when it isn't reading the time.  And it probably expects 12 hour time to run from 12:00 to 11:59.

Comment: Thanks guys... you are both correct... removing the 'a' solved the issue... all is well now.  Thank you both so much... SD